# Store data from 4 textboxes into a simple array

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox, binaryfiles

I need help with storing data from 4 textboxes into an array and writing the data to binary file.

### This is what I need to specifically:

Store the data from 4 textboxes into a simple array then add a save button which will:

- Store the information in the 4 text boxes to the array
- Add the information in the 4 text boxes as four separate items to a binary
  file books.dat which is sorted by Title

This is my code so far:

### Concatenate Button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string[] strArray = new string[8];
      int index1 = 0;
      string text1 = this.txtAuthor.Text;
      strArray[index1] = text1;
      int index2 = 1;
      string str1 = ", ";
      strArray[index2] = str1;
      int index3 = 2;
      string text2 = this.txtDate.Text;
      strArray[index3] = text2;
      int index4 = 3;
      string str2 = ". ";
      strArray[index4] = str2;
      int index5 = 4;
      string text3 = this.txtTitle.Text;
      strArray[index5] = text3;
      int index6 = 5;
      string str3 = ". ";
      strArray[index6] = str3;
      int index7 = 6;
      string text4 = this.txtPublisher.Text;
      strArray[index7] = text4;
      int index8 = 7;
      string str4 = ".";
      strArray[index8] = str4;
      this.txtOutput.Text = string.Concat(strArray);          
    }
```

### Protected Override:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
      if (disposing && this.components != null)
        this.components.Dispose();
      base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

### Initialize Component:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
            this.txtAuthor = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.txtDate = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.txtTitle = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.txtPublisher = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.txtOutput = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.btnSave = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // txtAuthor
            // 
            this.txtAuthor.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 27);
            this.txtAuthor.Name = "txtAuthor";
            this.txtAuthor.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.txtAuthor.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 53);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(418, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button1.Text = "Concatenate";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // txtDate
            // 
            this.txtDate.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(120, 27);
            this.txtDate.Name = "txtDate";
            this.txtDate.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.txtDate.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // txtTitle
            // 
            this.txtTitle.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(226, 27);
            this.txtTitle.Name = "txtTitle";
            this.txtTitle.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.txtTitle.TabIndex = 4;
            // 
            // txtPublisher
            // 
            this.txtPublisher.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(332, 27);
            this.txtPublisher.Name = "txtPublisher";
            this.txtPublisher.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.txtPublisher.TabIndex = 6;
            // 
            // txtOutput
            // 
            this.txtOutput.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 82);
            this.txtOutput.Name = "txtOutput";
            this.txtOutput.ReadOnly = true;
            this.txtOutput.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(418, 20);
            this.txtOutput.TabIndex = 8;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(11, 11);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 13);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 9;
            this.label1.Text = "Author";
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this.label2.AutoSize = true;
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(117, 11);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 13);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 10;
            this.label2.Text = "Date";
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this.label3.AutoSize = true;
            this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(223, 11);
            this.label3.Name = "label3";
            this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(27, 13);
            this.label3.TabIndex = 11;
            this.label3.Text = "Title";
            // 
            // label4
            // 
            this.label4.AutoSize = true;
            this.label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(329, 11);
            this.label4.Name = "label4";
            this.label4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 13);
            this.label4.TabIndex = 12;
            this.label4.Text = "Publisher";
            // 
            // btnSave
            // 
            this.btnSave.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 108);
            this.btnSave.Name = "btnSave";
            this.btnSave.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(418, 23);
            this.btnSave.TabIndex = 13;
            this.btnSave.Text = "Save";
            this.btnSave.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnSave.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnSave_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(446, 142);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnSave);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label4);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtOutput);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtPublisher);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtTitle);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtDate);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtAuthor);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Book Details";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();
    }
```

### Book Class:

```
private class Book
    {
      private string Author
      {
        get
        {
          return this.Author;
        }
        set
        {
          this.Author = value;
        }
      }

      private string Date
      {
        get
        {
          return this.Date;
        }
        set
        {
          this.Date = value;
        }
      }

      private string Title
      {
        get
        {
          return this.Title;
        }
        set
        {
          this.Title = value;
        }
      }

      private string Publisher
      {
        get
        {
          return this.Publisher;
        }
        set
        {
          this.Publisher = value;
        }
      }
    }
```

### Empty Save Button:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         
        }
```

Comment: So where is your problem? What did you try, where are you stuck?

Comment: @nvoigt I don't know how to store data from the 4 textboxes respectively into the array. Also, I don't know how to save the details of the books to a binary file.

Comment: So, what *do* you know? Do you know how to create an array? How to create an array of fixed texts? Did you try the same with your texts? The point is that you want code written and at the same time show no research effort. That's not how this site works.

Comment: @nvoigt There's no need to get hostile. I don't know what's wrong with me. I seem to have trouble with code no matter how simple or how complex, it's like, I look at explanations on the internet, many of whom I feel resonate with my tasks but I don't get it at all. Is there something that new programmers need to do before they actually start coding? Everywhere I look for help, people say it's so simple and ask me how I don't get it? You don't understand my situation; I've been coding for half a year now and don't understand much at all.

Comment: You need to read a book. Programming is not easy, but asking "how to do this" for every step is not the way to learn.

Comment: I've been coding for half  year now and I need help for every little thing. I've read books, done tasks after chapters but I just don't get it so please don't assume you know my stance because you don't. Everyone here seems to think beginners are lazy and don't research, it's getting on my nerves. I've done my research except I understand close to nothing the research suggests for me to do.

Comment: Then you need to take a step back and start from where you now how to do things. Do you know how to save a single string to file?

Comment: I don't how to do that.

Comment: Then why are you looking to write an array of string to a binary file? You are trying to fly a jetfighter when you cannot even jump from the edge of your bed yet. You are a beginner. It takes years to get better and know stuff. Do beginners' tasks to learn. We all did that. There are no shortcuts.

Comment: @nvoigt I've done a quick search and found out how to do it, I look at things in a weird way, perhaps over-analyse. One question though; In my code provided, does it already contain the code for storing user input from the textboxes into an array already? Is it already there?

Comment: Yes it is. A lot more complicated then need be, but it's there.

Comment: Far out! I didn't even notice that I did it. I over-think everything I swear! Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you are going about this the wrong way. My understanding of the problem is that you want to create your "Book" class from the 4 inputs in your GUI, which is Serializable. In this case I would modify your book class to contain a constructor which takes 4 arguments (title, author, publisher and date):

```
internal class Book
{
    public Book(string title, string author, string publisher, string date)
    {
        Title = title;
        Author = author;
        Publisher = publisher;
        Date = date;
    }

    public string Title { get; private set; }
    public string Author { get; private set; }
    public string Publisher { get; private set; }
    public string Date { get; private set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}, {1}. {2}. {3}.", Author, Date, Title, Publisher);
    }
}
```

Then your button1_Click method can look like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var title = this.txtTitle.Text;
    // var author, date, publisher are similar

    this.currentBook = new Book(title, author, publisher, date);
}
```

Where currentBook is a member variable of type Book.

Finally your save button method would now look like:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentBookText = this.currentBook.ToString();

    // write currentBookText to file. 
}
```

You can look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx for information about writing to a file.

You could then easily create a `public static Book Book.FromString(string input)` method to de-serialize your book files.

C# can also handle the serialization and de-serialization for you. For more information look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et91as27.aspx

Comment: For the currentBook member variable: do a create a new instance of book?

Comment: That depends on how you are using it. The way I have suggested is to create a new instance of book, and when you click save it will only save the most recent book.

Alternatively you may wish to have a `IList<Book> books = new List<book>()`, and call `books.Add(new Book(...));` which will allow users to define multiple books and save them all at once?

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error for currentBook. "Does not contain a definition" and "No extension method". Perhaps I've forgotten to mention some key details and that's why your suggestion code isn't working? Although everything except for the currentBook parts is working fine.

Comment: Also if you don't mind could you tell me where the:
IList<Book> books = new List<book>(), and call books.Add(new Book(...)); part goes in the code?

Comment: The does not contain a definition means that you have not defined currentBook. You need current book to be a member variable of the GUI class. This means somewhere in the class where you define `button1_click` and `save_click` you need to define `private Book currentBook`.

Comment: For the method with lists, replace `private Book currentBook;` with the definition of the list, and replace the call to `this.currentBook...` with the call to Add

Comment: OK thanks but I don't think you explained how to save array to .dat file?

Comment: I left a link to a MSDN article about how to write a string to file. The Book class's tostring method will return a string.